# Integration with google hangouts and ibm watson

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, google-hangouts

Is there any way in which I can integrate Google hangouts with IBM watson...I have created a bot through node js and i want to interface that bot with google hangouts where the conversation will be fetched from ibm watson

Answer (score 1):

Just like API.AI can be delivered with Hangouts using `http requests`, you can do the same using Watson Conversation, remembering that is one REST API endpoint, so you can build one Hangout API which is javascript based integrating with Watson Conversation.

- Check this project using [Google hangouts](https://github.com/xmikos/hangupsbot) with other bot.

There are bots integrated to it that you can follow the same logic, only sending the return of the Watson converstation in each interaction of the user, obtaining the answer and sending the user again.

- Official Documentation to use [Hangout API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started).
- Reference: [here](https://discuss.api.ai/t/can-i-integrate-hangouts-chat-by-api-ai/3729).